# Firebase Function using request library not firing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, request, google-cloud-functions

Almost there, but for some reason my HTTP post request isn't firing and eventually the function timesout.  Completely beside myself and posting my code to see if anyone picks up on any noob moves that I'm completely missing.  NOTE:  the database write completes so I'm assuming that the HTTP Post request isn't firing, is that a safe assumption?  Or JS is a different beast?

```
exports.stripeConnect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var code = req.query.code;
    const ref = admin.database().ref(`/stripe_advisors/testing`);
    var dataString = `client_secret=sk_test_example&code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code`;
    var options = {
            url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
            method: 'POST',
            body: dataString
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body);
            }
    }

    request(options, callback);
    return ref.update({ code: code });
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with firebase? It looks like you are trying to connect to stripe? What http library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to POST to https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token by using the `request` library and, on success, you want to write the `code` value to the database.

You should use promises, in your Cloud Function, to handle asynchronous tasks. By default request does not return promises, so you need to use an interface wrapper for request, like [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

Therefore, the following should normally do the trick:

```
.....
var rp = require('request-promise');
.....

exports.stripeConnect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var code = req.query.code;
    const ref = admin.database().ref('/stripe_advisors/testing');
    var dataString = `client_secret=sk_test_example&code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code`;
    var options = {
            url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
            method: 'POST',
            body: dataString
    };

    rp(options)
    .then(parsedBody => {
        return ref.update({ code: code });
    .then(() => {
        res.send('Success');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });

});
```

Comment: What do you get with `parsedBody`? (when the promise resolves in the then)?

Comment: Don't forget to install request-promise (`npm install --save request-promise`)

Comment: So it works by removing .then(() => bc it throws an unexpected token error and manually stopping the website.  If I just let the website run, it continously tries and stripe eventually rejects the token.  To combat that, going to use the Firebase write of the token as an indicator to redirect user to different website.  Imagine there's a much better way to do it in JS so all ears to suggestions.