# response.send is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a firebase function for the webhook fulfillment of dialogflow chatbot. It keeps generating error that response.send is not a function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request1 = require('request')
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        console.log("request.body.result.parameters: ", request.body.result.parameters);
        let params = request.body.result.parameters;
        var options = {
            url: `https://islam360api.herokuapp.com/${params.find}`,
            json:true
        }
        request1(options, function(error, response, body){
            if(error) response.send({speech: "error in API call"});
            else response.send({speech: body.speech});
        });
    });
```

Firebase Logs
[image]

Comment: Could you please try running it after changing name of 2nd parameter in request1() callback from response to response1?

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan response1.send is not a function

Comment: Have you tried logging response1 to see what it is and what methods are available?

Comment: @user9181286 doesnt matter if its response or response1 because AFAIK function arguments are used up in the order defined, so you can probably change response in `request1(options, function(error, response, body){` to `request1(options, function(error, res, body){` also. Right now you are trying to send response on the inner response which is result from the api call you made and not response parameter of your webhook.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan res.send is not a function

Comment: @user9181286 i know that but why do you keep changing these part `if(error) response.send({speech: "error in API call"});
            else response.send({speech: body.speech});` This doesnt requre any change. What i mean is .send() has to be called on response parameter of the top function and not inner function.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan I got it. It worked. You may add it as answer and I will mark it as correct

Comment: @user9181286 Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656564/request-not-returning-write-to-database-just-shows-the-console/50661074#50661074 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525371/firebase-function-using-request-library-not-firing/52525978#52525978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** this is a problem of shadow variable name, when you are trying to send response using firebase functions response object, in fact you are sending response back on response object of npm request module which is ofcourse not possible

**Solution:**
just put an underscore or change the spelling and you are ready to go, have a look of code:
(notice change in 5th line from bottom)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request1 = require('request')
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        console.log("request.body.result.parameters: ", request.body.result.parameters);
        let params = request.body.result.parameters;
        var options = {
            url: `https://islam360api.herokuapp.com/${params.find}`,
            json:true
        }
        request1(options, function(error, _response, body){
            if(error) response.send({speech: "error in API call"});
            else response.send({speech: body.speech});
        });
    });
```